# Actionscript 3 Playing videos back to back with in a sequence with no break inbetween

Tags: actionscript-3, video

I'm wondering at the possiblitity of setting up an array of videos that play back to play with absolutely no pause in between? Is there anyway to set it up that there is no way to to have any buffering or pause in between sequential playback? For example:

```
import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;

var videos:Array = new Array("Ad01.flv", "Ad02.flv", "Ad03.flv");
var currentVideo:uint = 0;
var duration:uint = 0;
var ready:Boolean = true;

var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
myVideo.attachNetStream(ns);
ns.play(videos[currentVideo]);

var listener:Object = new Object();
listener.onMetaData = function(evt:Object):void {
duration = evt.duration;
ready = true;
};

ns.client = listener;

ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,nsHandler );

function nsHandler(evt:NetStatusEvent):void {
if (ready && ns.time > 0 && ns.time >= (duration - 0.5)) {
ready = false;
currentVideo++;
if (currentVideo < videos.length) {
ns.play(videos[currentVideo]);
} else {
ns.removeEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, nsHandler
);
}
}
};
```

I'd like to break up one video into multiple parts and have it play seamlessly back. I've tested the above but I need to know definitively.

Comment: Are the videos local?   You'll probably want to pre-load the next video in the queue prior to the current one ending to ensure seamlessness

Comment: No.  You can only come close with lots of work.  You can use two video players and switch back and forth.  The best solution is to have breakpoints in the video that won't be affected by a bad cut - if the video skips ahead or back half a second.  The best is fade to black scene transition, change the video when it's black and there's no sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could do it is to embed the videos to the timeline of separate swfs, and then subload the swfs, and play each timeline when needed after all the loads are complete.

Comment: This is usually the best way to go about it if you want absolutely no pauses/breaks.